# why does Form.Modal property doesn't have a setter?

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't understand why this property doesn't have a setter. What would happen if you were able to set this property?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Form.ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog)?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'm not looking for that method I was wondering it was possible to change the modal state of a form after it was shown.

Comment: No, that's not possible as explained in the answers below. As I mentioned in my answer, if you need to understand exactly why, read [Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/4934172) to the linked question in order to know how `ShowDialog()` accomplishes that.

Comment: Thanks i dont understand why my question is downvoted....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, it depends on *how the form is currently being used*, I.e. whether it was [`Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)ed or [`ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)ed. Whilst the form is being shown, it doesn't make *sense* to allow you to change it's modality<sup>1</sup>.

When the form isn't being shown, it also doesn't make sense to have this be a settable property since what matters is whether the next use of the form is via `Show` or `ShowDialog`.

Whilst it's true that most forms will only ever be shown *either* modally or non-modally, the option remains open to use a single form in both manners.

---

<sup>1</sup>Especially because when a form is being shown modally via `ShowDialog`, the code calling `ShowDialog` is blocked until it returns with the *result* of the dialog. If you were to change a form to be modal after it was already `Show`n, there's nobody waiting to receive the dialog result when it returns.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `Form.Modal` property, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.modal):

> Gets a value indicating whether this form is displayed modally.

So, it only checks for the modal status of the form. It doesn't make sense for it to have a setter.

In order to open a form modally, you should use the [`ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) method, *also as explained in the link above*. That way when you check for the `Modal` property, it returns true.

If your question is whether or not you can have a modal form *after it's been shown*, the answer is **no**, you can't. To understand why, you need to know how `ShowDialog()` makes the form modal in the first place. Check this [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/4934172) by Hans Passant in order to understand how `ShowDialog()` works *at a technical level*.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why this property doesn't have a setter. What would
>   happen if you were able to set this property?

It doesn't have a setter because you cant change its *Modal* style once the *Form* has been shown. Although subtle, *Modal* and and *Non Modal* forms behave differently in regards to owner, and blocking the caller, and other less obvious things. It seemingly just not worth the confusion of adding this i would imagine.

Further more, users must interact with the Modal/Dialog window before they can return to the parent application. This avoids interrupting the workflow on the main window and by design.

So if you want a *Modal Form*, call `ShowDialog()` or else call `Show()`